# Subdomain A record Resolves, but Nameservers won't

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, subdomain, nameserver

I have a domain xyz.com, which resolves to an IP: 192.168.1.128

```
Nameservers: ns1.named.com
             ns2.named.com
```

Now I have a subdomain, webmail.xyz.com which points to 192.168.1.129

The zone file xyz.con.zone records is provided below:

```
;; A Records
xyz.com.            IN  A   192.168.1.128
mail.xyz.com.       IN  A   192.168.1.129
webmail.xyz.com.    IN  A   192.168.1.129

;; CNAME Records
www.xyz.com.    IN  CNAME   xyz.com.

;; NS Records
ns1.named.com.    IN    NS  named.com
ns2.named.com.    IN    NS  named.com
```

P.S: It's for an Intranet which is completely disconnected from the Internet.

The NS as well as the A records of the main domain xyz.com resolves when checking with any DNS tools like nslookup or dig.

But for mail.xyz.com and webmail.xyz.com the A records are resolved properly, but the NS records doesn't seem to resolve.

Any guess what is the issue ???

Comment: A given zonefile can only have names in the same zone, by definition. Your example (badly obfuscated) mixes at least two domain names in the same zonefile, which will never work. You mention `bind` so you can run `naned-checkzone` on your file and it will tell you everything that is wrong in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your NS records are wrong. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, what are the IP addresses / names of the nameservers for `xyz.com`? (BTW, if xyz.com is not your domain, use example.com when replacing the real name.)

You have now added 2 nameserver records, designating `named.com` (note also the missing trailing dot, so probably actually `named.com.xyz.com.`) as *the* nameserver for the domain `ns1.named.com` and also for `ns2.named.com`. I also don't know if using different domains in the same zonefile will actually work...

If your intention was to use `ns1.named.com` and `ns2.named.com` as the nameservers for your xyz.com domain, then those records should be:

```
xyz.com.    IN    NS    ns1.named.com.
xyz.com.    IN    NS    ns2.named.com.
```

Comment: "use example.com when replacing the real name."  this is indeed the good way to obfuscate and it is explained in RFC2606. Same idea for IP addresses, covered in RFC5737 do not use blind any IP and not private space IP addresses blocks (because those should not appear in the DNS to avoid rebinding attack), but in short use block 192.0.2.0/24